# how does the network interface card know what application to forward packets to?

Tags: http, networking, tcp

For the last few days, I've been learning about networking and I used wireshark to sniff my network traffic, I wondered how packets arrive to the same application they were requested by! Namely when I type in "https://stackoverflow.com" in my browser, the requested page gets sent to the same browser that requested it.

Using wireshark, I found that the application name is sent along with the http header, in this form:
{User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36}

I thought this is how the webserver knows which application to forward packets to. So, I thought the response is going to contain the name of the browser I was using in the request but I found that the packet doesn't seem to contain this information at all! Now the question is, how does my computer know which application should it forward the packet to !!

It can even get more complicated if I would think about what tap did I use to request the page, surely such details are not going to be sent in the packet. So I'm just wondering, how does the page load on the same page using the same application ?! Maybe there is a session ID or something sent in the request and then received back in the response ??? If so, how can I find that ID in the packet using wireshark ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP protocol uses PORTS to make connection to different applications between different IP address. And your Operating System manages outgoing connections and assigns new PORTs to new requests. Connection (session) is `IP_Address1:TCP_Port1 => IP_Adress2:TCP_Port2`

Answer (score 0):

> How does hhe network interface card know what application to forward packets to?

It doesn't.

The TCP/IP network stack in the operating system does that, via the port numbers in the protocol.